# shiftKey in Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Is there any way to determine in javascript whether shift key is pressed on mobile keyboard, and distinguish it from the caps lock(twice pressed shift key)

Comment: This seems to be an oooold issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4555006/561731

Comment: Do you need handle it via iOS SDK or via Web site?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander I am ***assuming*** a website.

Comment: With my iPod 4.3 in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAwLM/), the shift key isn't detected at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Some Facts

First, let's look at some facts about iOS keyboards I assume you already know:

- When you enter the keyboard mode, the `shift` key is always activated
- `Caps Lock` must be activated manually (I guess this is not used too widely)

#### iPhone Shift Key Handling

I investigated a bit into this issue, and here's what I found:

- The `shift` Key triggers no key Event
- There is no special iPhone Browser API to detect whether the shift key is pressed or not, except in an iOS App (duh)
- The `keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup` event triggered by iOS look normal, except they do not indicate shiftKey usage, and apart from their timestamp and type cannot be distinguished.
- You cannot manually dispatch a Keyboard Event in iOS because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript), `keyCode` and `which` are readonly and always set to `0`. Retriggering a Keyboard event to get some indication about the shift key still being on is impossible.
- Actually, The iPhone treats the `shift` key like some sort of `Short Term Caps Lock` key. The difference is that normally, you activate it once, and it deactivates automatically.

#### What can be done

I assume you want to indicate on an input field whether the user should be careful about having Shift/Caps Lock pressed (a password field, for example). What I came up with is some sort of a workaround, but I think it's better than nothing.

[You can also test the jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JW6XC/).

**DOM Setup**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <label for="test">ENTER SOMETHING HERE</label>
  <input type="text" name="test" id="test"/>
</div>
<div id="warning"></div>​
```

**Javascript**

This checks wheter the user did enter capitalized input, and it assumes the user is using `caps lock` if two capitalized letters where entered.

```
var isCaps = false,
isUppercase = false,
str = '',
test = document.getElementById('test'),
warning = document.getElementById('warning');

function capsDetection(e) {

    // Since where on iOS, we at least don't have to care 
    // about cross-browser stuff
    var s = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    isCaps = isUppercase;

    // if the char doesn't match its lower case friend, and the shift key is 
    // not pressed (which is always the case on iOS, but we leave it there 
    // for readability), we have uppercase input
    isUppercase = (s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey);

    // if its the second uppercase input in a row, we may have caps lock input
    isCaps = isCaps && isUppercase;

    // set the warning
    if (isUppercase && !isCaps) {
        str = 'You where using the shift key';
    }
    else if (isCaps) {
        str = 'Caps lock seems to be activated';
    } else {
        str = '';
    }
    warning.innerHTML = str;
}

// the right event properties are only available on keypress
test.addEventListener('keypress', capsDetection);
```

As I said, better than nothing, but not a solution if you need to know the shift key is pressed without the user doing any input. That seems to be impossible right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible with Javascript. It is possible with objective C though.

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchEventClassReference/TouchEvent/TouchEvent.html